# Getting an InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> for Jenkins when attempting to pull from SCM

Tags: jenkins

When building a project on jenkins during the initial stages which involves pulling new files froma Git repos, the pulling fails and the build does not proceed.

This is the console output during the build

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\xxxxxxx
FATAL: Illegal char <:> at index 5: https://xxxxxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxxxx.git
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 5: https://xxxxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxxxx.git
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.abortIfSourceIsLocal(GitSCM.java:1399)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1282)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:540)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1217)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:647)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:519)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1897)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is anyone else experiencing this and knows how to resolve it?

To be clear, Jenkins was building sucessfully yesterday and after applying some updates today morning to Jenkins, the failure occurred. I rolled back the Jenkins update but still have this issue

Comment: Maybe someone has created a branch or tag with an illegal character in the name. Verify in your repo, look for accents,  ': ', and that kind of things

Comment: I was having the same problem, after updating the plugins. There is a bug in the Git-Plugin version 4.11.2 for nodes running on windows.
Take a look here:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#releases
Just update your plugin to Version 4.11.3

Comment: I was getting the same problem with the Mercurial plugin, the latest version fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem in the Git plugin as Asturio mentioned. They have released a hotfix and after updating to the latest version, we're good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Update the git plugin of Jenkins to version 4.11.3, it has fixed this bug. Do it from Jenkins Manager --> Manage Plugins --> Updates for git